# Shopify oauth using Aws Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, shopify, aws-api-gateway, shopify-app

I want to perform the authorization of Shopify app using `Aws Lambda`. I have created a `public app` in Shopify admin. I have kept the `redirect uri` of the app as api's endpoint from `Api Gateway` which triggers the Lambda. In this lambda, I am just printing the event.

I am testing this on a *development store*. So when I generate *auth url* and click on that it takes me to the Shopify page where it asks me to install the app on my store. When I click on install, the url is redirected to api endpoint with some added query params like `code`, `hmac`, `timestamp` etc and the Lambda is triggered which prints "Hello" on the console. I checked the lambda logs to see if I have received this url in the event or not. But it is null.

I want the redirect url with code in my lambda so that I can extract authorization code, hmac  from there. How can I do this?

[shopify oauth link](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-with-oauth)

Comment: Maybe you should provide of your Lambda. If the event is null it might be a code issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by mapping the query in api gateway. And you can easily do this by enabling proxy integration.